Outside-mounted kitchen exhaust fan is loud inside

I have a range exhaust in my kitchen that is ducted to the outside. The fan is located on the outside of the house. It is very loud from the inside of the home. Not so much from outside.
Humming and rattling noise.
I removed the filter plates and that didn’t change anything. So it’s not that. Wondering if chad going out the fan will work? Or removing the fan and attaching a range hood to the ceiling?

Replace the fan. Some fans have a sound rating (e.g., https://ventahood.com/index.php/about/innovation/magic-lung). Look for one with a low sone rating.

Can you tell if it's the fan and/or motor being loud, or the enclosure?  Like, if you operate the fan, and go outside and hold onto the enclosure with your hands (damping the sound), does that make it less noisy?
